# npm install -g expo-cli fails with "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '...\adb.exe'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

I receive an error when running

```
$ npm install -g expo-cli
```

I have tried reinstalling the node modules as An Administrator but the same error occurs.

**Environment:**
Windows 10,
Node Version: `10.15.3`,
NPM Version: `6.9.0`

I expect the install to happen but an error like this occurs:

> npm ERR! path
>   C:\Users\Griseld\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe
>   npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall unlink npm
>   ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\Griseld\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe'
>   npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Users\Griseld\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe']
>   npm ERR!   cause: npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
>   unlink
>   'C:\Users\Griseld\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe'
>   npm ERR!      errno: -4048, npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!
>   syscall: 'unlink', npm ERR!      path: npm ERR!
>   'C:\Users\Griseld\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe'
>   }, npm ERR!   stack: npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not
>   permitted, unlink
>   \'C:\Users\Griseld\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe\'',
>   npm ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM', npm ERR!   syscall:
>   'unlink', npm ERR!   path: npm ERR!
>   'C:\Users\Griseld\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe',
>   npm ERR!   parent: 'expo-cli' } npm ERR! npm ERR! The operation was
>   rejected by your operating system. npm ERR! It's possible that the
>   file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus), npm ERR! or
>   that you lack permissions to access it. npm ERR! npm ERR! If you
>   believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the npm
>   ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try
>   running npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this
>   is not recommended).

Comment: Are you running an android emulator or connecting the device when you install it?

Comment: android emulator

Comment: When you install, try installing without running any programs related to Android.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Go through this line from your error log, it says
'C:\Users\Griseld\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\adb.exe' npm ERR!

the expo cli wasn't installing simply because your adb is still using the previously installed expo cli on your system.
had similar issue not quite long...kill the process adb.exe

Comment: Yeap, killing the adb.exe process fixed the problem

Comment: Wow I cannot believe I had to come here to find this obvious solution :) thanks a lot Frank

Comment: anytime @NielsBrinch

Comment: Thank you! This is why I love stack overflow

Answer (score 3):

Go to your task manager and kill the process of Adb.exe and boom.

Answer (score 2):

More Simple Solution For Windows 10 Close The Android Emulator.

And restart the system and run `npm install -g expo-cli`

Answer (score 2):

The steps I followed (May this follow help you.)

1. npm uninstall -g expo-cli (If already have installed any version on your machine)
2. npm clear cache --force
3. Killed Abd.exe from Task Manager
4. npm uninstall -g expo-cli

It worked for me, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, stopping the webpack server did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Simply deleting "android/app/build" fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps

1. Open Task Manager - right-click on the task bar and select it, or from the screen when you Ctrl-Alt-Delete. If you have the standard Task Manager, click to expand More details. (If you're using something like Process Explorer, you're probably comfortable finding your own way.)
2. In the Background processes click on adb.exe (32 bit) (or, presumably, something similar). Click End task or press Delete to kill the process. This should unlock the problematic files.
3. This is probably not necessary - I deleted the folder that contained the files that caused the error in the first place, .xdl-DELETE. (I would expect npm to do it for me but I was testing my hypothesis .) Remember to close any command prompts or Explorer windows afterwards, because otherwise you'll be locking the expo-cli folder. (I'd left an Explorer window open in that folder which is why I mention it ‍♂️.)
4. Run npm i -g expo-cli to update. You'll have time to make a cup of tea while it's going, so I suggest doing that.