# Installing expo cli using npm is not working

Tags: npm, request, expo

I had decided to start learning react native app development, and as the tutorials suggested, the first step was to install expo-cli.
Thus, running `npm install expo-cli --global`.
But, everytime, I run on the second step to install `request@2.88.2`, the install/download gets stuck.
The screen where it is stuck has the message:

```
⸨░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░⸩ ⠦ fetchMetadata: WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
```

I tried cleaning the npm cache by running the command `npm cache clean --force`, but the result was still the same.

I opened the given issue link, but to no avail, as it just mentions that request has been deprecated. I really wanted to know if there could be some way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

this is just a warning and it does not prevent installation

Comment: Exactly, that is the expectation. But, still the download has been stuck at that for a long time

Comment: i would suggest trying out using yarn instead if npm isn't working for you. it's really hard to debug installation and configuration issues with npm on different machines remotely through stackoverflow. if you've tried unisntalling and reinstalling it and that doesn't help, then give yarn classic a try https://classic.yarnpkg.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning. Installation probably waits a service or an app to be completed. In my case, if I wait adequate time (approx 4 min) the installation throws an error similar to below (just first lines...):

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinApi.dll'
...
...
```

The solution in my case is, stopping the running app/task "adb.exe" using my task manager, and  then trying to re-install expo-cli. All clear.
Check your error message carefully, and try to find which app/task causes the installation hanging. Stopping that app probably will allow you to install expo-cli.

Same solution advised in [npm install -g expo-cli fails with "EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink '...\adb.exe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193800/npm-install-g-expo-cli-fails-with-eperm-operation-not-permitted-unlink)